# How to Same Signature in asp.net Webservices?

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I would like to create two methods with the same signature and same return type in asp.net web service. How can i create that.

Could you please give me any suggestion or sample for the same.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: you wouldn't. it applies to anything in general. why would you want to have 2 methods the same? The compiler wouldn't know which one to call because they would be the same signature and types. Try it and you will see it will not compile.

Comment: Yes you right. i was trying it shows compilation error for me. i Just want to know is there any possibility to create like that. Just curious.

Comment: none at all. you also need to ask yourself would it make sense to do so? it wouldn't - how would you distinguish between the 2 if it were possible? Again... you wouldn't. if things are identical, how can you know which one you want? you wouldn't.... :)